# php pdo query gives different result when using it separately comparing with using it with function

Tags: php

i have a class called DB which contains a method CheckEmail which take one parameter stored the email. this method check if the email inserted is already exist in the database or not. when using the block of codes inside this method separately it works fine but when calling this method and pass email it doesn't work and the query return 0 always even though the email inserted exist in the database:

```
Class DB{
        private static function connect(){
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=testdb; charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $pdo;
        }

        public static function CheckEmail($email){
            $sql = "SELECT email from users where email = :email";
            $stmt = self::connect()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(["email"=> $email]);
            var_dump($stmt->execute(["email"=> $email]));
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            var_dump($count);//$count is always 0
            if($count > 0){
                return true;
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Are you sure `$email` is correct when you call the function? Make sure it doesn't have extra whitespace.

Comment: $email = 'hkane@test.com' is stored in the database. if i call the method like this DB::CheckEmail($email) it doesn't return true because $count is 0 always but if execute the sequence of the statements alone without having a class it works and return 1.

Comment: Put `var_dump($email)` in the function and make sure it contains what you expect.

Comment: var_dump($email)>> string 'hkane@test.com' (length=14)

Comment: What does `var_dump($stmt->fetchAll())` show?

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: I'm out of ideas. There's PDO doesn't care how it's called, there's no difference between calling it from a class and calling it from other code.

Comment: There has to be some other difference.

Comment: Post the code that doesn't use the class.

Comment: `$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql = "SELECT email from users where email = :email";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(["email"=> $email]);
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());// 
var_dump($count);// 1
if($count > 0){
  echo 'email is in use';
 }`

Comment: Put the code in the question so it's readable. And include how you set `$pdo`.

Comment: what a silly mistake i made!, database name used in the class was wrong. once i fixed it works as expected. thx a lot for your help Barmar.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something simple like that.